# Add a view into modal asp.net MVC Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

I have a modal created where I will be displaying some details of my list items:

```
<li class="list-group-item"> <a data-toggle="modal" data-id="@item.JobID" data-target="#myModal">@item.JobID @item.JobTitle </a> </li>
```

I update my modal with the following JS:

```
 modalBody.load(@Html.Action("Details", new { id = 29})):


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var list = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var clickedButtonId = list.data('id');
        var jobdetails = list.data('status');
        var details = list.data('src');
        //select modal body
        var modalBody = $('#myModal .modal-body');
        //load the content of your partial view into the modal body
        modalBody.load(details);
    }).modal();
})
```

UPDATE:
This still doesn't work

I would also like to pass a view inside that modal that will get the same ID. 
I've found a way of just passing it using an iframe but I know that's not recommended any more.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why an iframe? Why not a DIV, for example?

Comment: I'm saying that i don';t want to use an iframe but thats the only thing I've used in the past. But I'm not that great with Jquery and I'm not sure how to populate details view inside that modal.

Comment: If you were using angular you could just point the `templateUrl` of a `directive` to your `url` you want to show. Not really home in using ASP.NET MVC though.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need to be so complicated:

1. Hook up a click event to an anchor inside the `<li>`
2. Retrieve the job id by accessing `data-id` of the clicked item
3. Make an ajax call using `$.getJSON` to get the job details
4. Display the job details in a modal by calling `$('#myModal').modal('show');`

**Controller:**

public class Job
    {
        public int JobID { get; set; }
        public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    }

```
public class JobController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var j1 = new Job { JobID = 1, JobTitle = "Software Developer" };
        var j2 = new Job { JobID = 2, JobTitle = "Business Analyst" };
        var j3 = new Job { JobID = 3, JobTitle = "Project Manager" };

        var jobs = new List<Job> { j1, j2, j3 };

        return View(jobs);
    }

    public JsonResult GetJobDetails(int id)
    {
        //Write the code to look up the job details based on id(I'm hardcoding for simplicity)
        return Json(new { WorkingHours = "06:00 - 15:00", IsContractor = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCTutorial.Controllers.Job>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Jobs</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".list-group-item a").click(function () {
                var id = $(this).data('id');
                alert(id);

                if(id != "")
                {
                    $.getJSON("/Job/GetJobDetails/" + id, function (data) {

                        var workingHours = data.WorkingHours;
                        var isContractor = data.IsContractor;

                        var details = "Working hours - " + workingHours + ".Is contractor - " + isContractor;

                        $(".modal-body").empty();
                        $(".modal-body").html(details);

                        $('#myModal').modal('show');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="list-group">
        @foreach (var job in Model)
        {
            <li class="list-group-item"><a data-id="@job.JobID">@job.JobID @job.JobTitle</a></li>
        }
    </ul>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Jobs</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image: Displaying AJAX call results in modal popup using botstrap]